# apt-get doesn't load third-party PPA's

Tags: 11.04, server, apt, ppa

I have a server running Ubuntu Server 11.04, and when I add a PPA via `add-apt-repository`, `apt-get` doesn't load the PPA when I do `apt-get update`. It's specifically [this](https://launchpad.net/~jerome-etienne/+archive/neoip?field.series_filter=natty) PPA I need to add, but same thing happens for all the PPA's I've tried.

I have checked that the .list files are in fact created in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/, and if I add the PPAs' "string" directly in to /etc/apt/sources.list, it still doesn't work.

You can see [here](https://gist.github.com/952345) in action that I first add the PPA and then update, but the PPA's is not on the list of loaded archives. I have also done a s-trace something, that some guy on #ubuntu-server said I could try, and the PPA's I add are actually shown in it and "handled", but for some reason, they are still not getting "punched in use".

I hope somebody can help me with this.

By the way, this server is originally a 10.04.1 installation that has been upgraded to 10.10 and then to 11.04, if that can have something to do with it.

Thank you so far,
ChrisBuchholz

Comment: Link to the s-trace something: http://paste.ubuntu.com/602496/

Comment: indeed the ppa is empty but you could use the 10.10 packages, in the meantime, i don't think that it would crash the OS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that if the natty ppa is empty you will have to change it to maverick To get it to work.
You can also check the ppa's web site for what they have available.

Answer (score 3):

http://ppa.launchpad.net/jerome-etienne/neoip/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/binary-i386/Packages is empty so there aren't any binary packages for 11.04 in this PPA

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think the PPA is not loaded?

I just added the PPA and during the **apt-get update** there is no specific reference to the PPA.

If you change the path and add some random characters in the .list file, do you get any errors during the **apt-get update**

Comment: Well, alright. So I guess thats possible. But what makes me believe it's not loaded ultimately, is that I can't download the package. If I install the package `nodejs`, I get version from the ubuntu 'universe' archive. ´apt-cache show nodejs` also tells me that, thus, it seems like the package from PPA is not "punched in use". And yes, if I add some "random characters" to the .list file, `apt-get update` does indeed fail.